# Can you tell me PageSize Change Event in Kendo Angular grid

Tags: angularjs

Can you tell me page size Change event in Kendo-Angular grid as i am new in kendo grid control. Please help me. Thank you in advance.

```
app.controller("dataController", function ($compile, dataFactory, $scope, $timeout) {
$scope.obj = [];
$scope.DistrictList = [];
$scope.DistrictTextToShow = "Select District";
$scope.GetDistrict = function () {
    dataFactory.getdistrictList().success(function (data) {
        $scope.DistrictList = data;
    }).error(function (data) {
        $.toaster({ priority: 'error', title: 'Error', message: 'Error while fetching data' });
    });

};

if ($("#ddldistrict").val() == '') {
    $scope.ddldistrict = GuidEmpty;
}
else {
    $scope.ddldistrict = $("#ddldistrict").val();
}
$scope.gridData = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    serverPaging: true,
    serverSorting: true,
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: baselocation + "api/Customer/GetAllCustomerByDistrictId",
            data: { DistrictId: $scope.ddldistrict, isactive: $("#ddlstatus").val() }

        }
    },
    schema: {
        data: function (data) {
            return data.Rows;
        },
        total: function (data) {
            return data.TotalRows;
        }
    },
    pageSize: 5

});

$scope.detailGridOptions = {
    sortable: true,
    pageable: {
        "pageSizes": true,
        change: function (e) {

            if ($("#ddldistrict").val() == '') {
                $scope.ddldistrict = GuidEmpty;
            }
            else {
                $scope.ddldistrict = $("#ddldistrict").val();
            }
            //$("#grid1").data('kendoGrid').dataSource.pageSize(parseInt(this.value()));
            $("#grid1").data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read({ DistrictId: $scope.ddldistrict, isactive: $("#ddlstatus").val() });
            $("#grid1").data('kendoGrid').refresh();

        }
    },
    datasource: $scope.gridData,
    groupable: true,
    scrollable: true,
    columns: [{
        field: "Customername",
        title: "Customer Name",
        width: "150px"
    }, {
        field: "mobile",
        title: "Mobile",
        width: "120px"
    }, {
        field: "email",
        title: "Email",
        width: "120px"
    }, {
        field: "Districtname",
        title: "District",
        width: "120px"
    }]

};


$scope.GetDistrict();

$scope.BindData = function () {
    if ($("#ddldistrict").val() == '') {
        $scope.ddldistrict = GuidEmpty;
    }
    else {
        $scope.ddldistrict = $("#ddldistrict").val();
    }
    $("#grid1").data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read({ DistrictId: $scope.ddldistrict, isactive: $("#ddlstatus").val() });
    $("#grid1").data('kendoGrid').refresh();

}


//$("#grid1").kendoPager({

//});



//$scope.gridData.read();
});
```